# Can't find/uninstall Discord

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, uninstall

When running the command `sudo apt-get --purge remove discord` or `sudo apt-get remove discord` I got this back:

`Reading package lists... Done`

`Building dependency tree`

`Reading state information... Done`

`E: Unable to locate package discord`

I want to uninstall it to reinstall it. The program file that opens it is this: /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=discord com.discordapp.Discord

Do I need to uninstall flatpak? How can I get rid of Discord to do a reinstall? The program also has a bwrap dependency when looking through System Monitor for some reason.

Comment: Right, if the app was installed with flatpak, then apt-get can't do anything with it. Run `flatpak list` in terminal and see if Discord gets listed. If yes, then run `flatpak --help` and read through the topics; uninstall will be among the first things in the help. `flatpak uninstall --help` will give more details about uninstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Discord is installed as a Flatpak on your system, and not natively through your package manager, thus `apt` and it's cow powers have no jurisdiction here. (run `apt moo` to help understand reference)

---

To simply remove:  `flatpak uninstall com.discordapp.Discord`

To remove Discord and it's related data (configs, etc.):  `flatpak uninstall --delete-data com.discordapp.Discord`

Comment: I uninstalled it already by just putting `flatpak uninstall discord` but all the data is still there. I tried doing the second command line you sent but it didn't work, how do I get rid of the other stuff now?

Comment: @kaiserkothe `rm -vr ~/.var/app/com.discordapp.Discord`